# Angular JS part of my html file is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am new to angular js. I wrote a small html file using some basic angular elements but all that angular part is not being rendered by the browser. My file is

```
<head>
<!-- adding  script files -->
    <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- adding  css files -->
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap     combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="container" ng-controller="CarouselCtrl">
            <div class="offsetspan6">
                 <carousel interval="myInterval">
                      <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
                            <img class="image-circle" ng-src="{{slide.image}}"      style="margin:auto;"/>
                     <div class="carousel-caption">
                         <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
                         <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
                   </div>
                   </slide>
            </carousel>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

I put all the required files in the lib directory. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Should initialize your app with ng-app.

```
<html ng-app>
.....
</html>
```